# Magento cms page display block tag instead of html in mobile site

Tags: magento

i am implementing magento mobile theme for mobile version but my index cms page display block tags instead of executing it's content. though html content works fine. below is my cms.xml code.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <!--
   Default layout, loads most of the pages
   -->
   <default>
      <reference name="footer">
  </reference>
   </default>

 <cms_index_index>
  <reference name="head">
     <action method="addJs">
        <script>aw_mobile/navigation.js</script>
     </action>
     <action method="addJs" ifconfig="awmobile/settings/scrolldisabled">
        <script>aw_mobile/scroll.js</script>
     </action>
     <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/navigation.css</stylesheet>
     </action>
  </reference>
  <block type="awmobile/catalog_navigation" name="cms_page" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml" >
     <block type="core/messages" name="nav_messages" as="nav_messages"/>
  </block>
  <default>
     <reference name="content">
        <block type="cms/block" name="home_page" as="home_page" output="toHtml">
           <action method="setBlockId">
              <block_id>home_page</block_id>
           </action>
        </block>
     </reference>
  </default>
   </cms_index_index>

   <cms_page>
  <reference name="content">
     <action method="setIsCms">
        <value>1</value>
     </action>
     <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
     <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
  </reference>
  <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
   </cms_page>

   <cms_index_defaultindex>
  <reference name="head">
     <action method="addJs">
        <script>aw_mobile/navigation.js</script>
     </action>
     <action method="addJs" ifconfig="awmobile/settings/scrolldisabled">
        <script>aw_mobile/scroll.js</script>
     </action>
     <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/navigation.css</stylesheet>
     </action>
  </reference>        
  <remove name="right"/>
  <remove name="left"/>
  <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
     </action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
     <block type="awmobile/catalog_navigation" name="cms_page" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml" >
        <block type="core/messages" name="nav_messages" as="nav_messages"/>
     </block>
  </reference>
   </cms_index_defaultindex>

   <cms_index_defaultnoroute>
  <remove name="right"/>
  <remove name="left"/>

  <reference name="root">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
     </action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
     <block type="core/template" name="default_no_route" template="cms/default/no-route.phtml"/>
  </reference>
  </cms_index_defaultnoroute>
</layout>
```

It display following output as it is in index page on mobile site

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe_popup.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Can you describe what is your task requirement? Actually what do you want to implement?

Comment: yes, whenever i call cms page which contains block tags like {{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe_popup.phtml"}}

it will display as it is on mobile site

Comment: Do you have file a mentioned location,if yes disable the show/hide editor and then put your code and try.

Comment: that i have done already.any other solution ?